# Unable to deploy Hyperledger Java chaincode via Github

Tags: git, blockchain, hyperledger

Following the intrustction at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/JAVAChaincode/, I was able to deploy a Hyperledger Java chaincode locally, that is:

1. Set up a validating peer
2. Write and build a Java chaincode locally, say in a directory X (which contains a `build.gradle` file)
3. Deploy successfully using `peer chaincode deploy -l java -p full_path_to_X -c ...`

But whenever I upload the chaincode directory to Github, and try this address during deploy:  `peer chaincode deploy -l java -p https://github.com/user/X`, I got the error:

`"Erro getting chaincode package bytes. Error cloning git repository exit status 128"`

It is not a problem with Git repository, for in it there is a Go chaincode, and I can deploy that Go chaincode successfully this way.

Would it be a problem with the Java container image used in Hyperledger has not had a feature to fetch a remote chaincode from Git?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happen, but I only could deploy the contract thought the REST:

Resquest - POST http://127.0.0.1:7050/chaincode

{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 4,
    "chaincodeID": {
      "path": "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/java/SimpleSample"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
      "function": "init",
      "args": [
        "a", "100", "b", "200"
      ]
    },
    "secureContext": "jim"
  },
  "id": 1
}

Response:

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"status":"OK","message":"0f5b1d65041bc6d500bd0f1cab50eb6154c291ef0f4596d64b6797e8ef8f7c34a179b5a2cea82253ff3d74e768512fe0481503eadcf13d18f9761bbb8133efd0"},"id":1}